# Cassandra datetime multi clustering columns filtering

Tags: cassandra

I'm using Cassandra 3.0, I created one table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE site (
    site_id bigint,    
   end_date timestamp,
    start_date timestamp,  
   promotion_id uuid,

   PRIMARY KEY (site_id, end_date,start_date, promotion_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (end_date DESC,start_date DESC, promotion_id ASC);
```

And I insert one record into this table

```
insert into site (site_id, start_date,end_date,promotion_id) values (10000,'2017-05-11T16:17:48','2017-05-21T16:17:48',8999f91c-a787-4604-9479-f8ead4955f6c);
```

May I ask why the following cql returns one record? I'm expecting it returns nothing:

```
select * from site
where site_id = 10000 and ( end_date, start_date ) <= ( '2117-05-12', '2017-04-12' );
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is also possible to “group” CLUSTERING COLUMNS together in a
>   relation using the tuple notation. For instance:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM posts
>  WHERE userid = 'john doe'
>    AND (blog_title, posted_at) > ('John''s Blog', '2012-01-01')
> ```
>
> will request all rows that sorts after the one having “John’s Blog” as
>   `blog_tile` and ‘2012-01-01’ for `posted_at` in the clustering order.
>   In particular, rows having a `posted_at <= '2012-01-01'` will be
>   returned as long as their `blog_title > 'John''s Blog'`, which would
>   not be the case for:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM posts
>  WHERE userid = 'john doe'
>    AND blog_title > 'John''s Blog'
>    AND posted_at > '2012-01-01'
> ```

this is from the cassandra documentation.

So in your case it will return all rows which has `end_date<=211705-12`

Comment: yes, I intended to use  end_date <= '2117-05-12' as I want it always returns true, but the start_date (2017-05-11) > '2017-04-12'.

May I ask if above cql  where clause has the same logic as where site_id = 1000 and end_date <= '2117-05-12' and start_date <= '2017-04-12'?